# Typescript: method signature based on generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've the following generic class:

```js
export class AClass<Data = void> {

refresh(data: Data): void {}

}
```

I would like the signature of the refresh method to be:

```js
refresh(){} // when Data = void
```

```js
refresh(data: Data){} // otherwise
```

I do not want to make the data argument optional

```js
refresh(data?: Data){} // not what I want because if data is different than "void" the arguments will be optional as well
```

The best I've been able to do is to use a variable holding a function instead of using a method.

```js
export class AClass<Data = void> {
    refresh: Data extends void ? () => void : (data: Data) => void = (...arg){
        console.log(...arg);
    }
}
```

I doubt we can have conditional method (class) signature defined within the same class, but is this accurate ?

[EDIT]
Why this question ?

Here is a TS class:

```js
class Example {
  aMethod () {
    console.log(`I am a method`)
  };

  aVariable = () => {console.log(`I am a variable holding a function`)}
}
```

This will be transpiled into this:

```js
"use strict";
class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.aVariable = () => { console.log(`I am a variable holding a function`); };
    }
    aMethod() {
        console.log(`I am a method`);
    }
    ;
}
```

We can clearly while both will eventually achieve the same however the method one is closer to the "native" es6 method implementation.
For this reason, I would like to find out if there is a way to type a class's method so that I will still be using a method instead of a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any issues with your code:

```
class AClass<T = void> {
    refresh(data: T): void {
        console.log(data);
    }
}

const instance = new AClass();

instance.refresh(); // log: undefined
instance.refresh('test'); // Compiler error

const instance2 = new AClass<string>();

instance2.refresh(); // Compiler error
// log: compiler error if not present
instance2.refresh('compiler error if not present');
```

transpiled to:

```
"use strict";
class AClass {
    refresh(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}
const instance = new AClass();
instance.refresh();
const instance2 = new AClass();
instance2.refresh('test');
```

Comment: The code is working but I am defining a class variable holding a function instead of a class method. Is there any way to achieve the same with a class method ?

Comment: Isnt `refresh` a class method ?

Comment: The code in my answer (and your question) will be transpiled to a method. So I still don't know where the issue is

Comment: It seems I had an angular (linter) issue complaining I had to pass an argument, using the variable instead of the method fixed the problem… so probably not directly related to TS. Thanks for helping me point this out.